# How to bind IFormFile back to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a mechanism for saving draft states of my Form before the user decides to publish the data. One of these fields is

```
<input asp-for="MyImage" type="file" class="form-control" />
```

When the draft is saved I store the file as a blob and when the user reloads the page I want to restore the data into the page elements.

My ViewModel is defined as

```
public class NewPostViewModel
{
    public PostViewModel NewPost { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile MyImage { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm reloading my page everything binds correctly except the FormFile.

I attempt to restore the image to the input by creating an instance of the ViewModel `vm` and instantiating the FormFile as follows

```
vm.MyImage = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, "MyImage", storedArticle.Filename);
```

I can see that `vm.MyImage` is populated with the data that I expect. But when I pass `vm` back to my View it doesn't populate the `input` with the data or the file name.

What do I need to do to make file upload input appear with the file it originally had before saving the draft?

Comment: Hi @DaveDev, Whether the reply has solved the problem or is there any update about this thread? If you have any question about my reply, please let me know freely.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it wasn't what i went with so i couldn't mark it correct. But it did give me the idea to help move forward a bit so I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are using `<input type="file" class="form-control" />` element, we can't set value for this element, due to security reasons.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to add a ImageName property in the View Model, then, when you save the draft, you could store the image name using the ImageName property.

```
public class NewPostViewModel
{
    public PostViewModel NewPost { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile MyImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you pass the `vm` back to the view page, in the View page(.csthml), you could check if the `ImageName` is empty or not.

If the `ImageName` is empty, it means you didn't select image previous, then, use the following element to select a new image:

```
 <input asp-for="MyImage" type="file" class="form-control"/>
```

If the `ImageName` is not empty, use an input text element to display the image name (in this scenario, when resubmits the form, the Image data might be empty, we should store them somewhere (such as: session)).

```
 <input asp-for="ImageName" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old. But I just ran into this problem myself and was able to solve it with the code below.

I'm not sure what framework your using currently I'm on .net 7.

Here's my css.

Here we style so that the input is hidden under the background image.

```
<style type="text/css">
.avatar-upload {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 205px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10px;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input {
    display: none;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-color: #d6d6d6;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:after {
    content: "\f040";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #757575;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-preview {
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 6px solid #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.avatar-upload .avatar-preview > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Here's my form on razor page.

Here we check if the Logo is null if not convert the FormFile to base64 string then attach it to the background img like so.

```
@page
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model User

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="UplaodImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@{
    //When model returns file is changed from FormFile to base64 string.
    //Placeholder file goes here.
    string icon = "http://i.pravatar.cc/500?img=7";
    @if (Model?.Logo != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
        {
            await Model.Logo.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            icon = $"data:image/png;base64{Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())}";
        }

    }
}


<div class="avatar-upload">
    <div class="avatar-edit">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Icon" type='file' id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
        <label for="imageUpload"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar-preview">
        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('@icon');">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input asp-for="@Model.Name" type='text'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit To Server</button> 


</form>
```

Here's my class

```
public class User
{
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Logo")]
    public IFormFile Logo{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [BindProperty]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Heres my Controller

Here we implement a basic call to the controller, which the model should not be valid because we left the Name field blank. When the call returns to view the Icon property will not be null and the image will load into background.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UplaodImage(User model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        byte[] logo = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
        {
            await model.Logo.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
            {
                logo = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            
        }
        //Model is Valid Do something with logo
    }
    else
    { 
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Name is required.");
    }
    //Model is not valid and will return to page with errors
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope this help someone that finds this thread with hopes for a solution.